# Converting elements list into single dictionary while scraping

Tags: python, list, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping Glassdoor companies. There is a benefits section which will be *different* for every company, so I am grabbing all the elements in the div. That returns a list. Is there anyway to convert these into `key:value` pairs *while* scraping. They need to be written to a `csv` inside a loop.

```
dict1 = {"Company URL": company_url, "Over All Rating": over_all_rating, "Most Commented":final, "Benefits":benefits, "Benefits List":all_ben_list}
    with open('Glassdoor.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
        if not header_added:
            w.writeheader()
```

[image]

As of now, I am writing the list in 1 column like so.

```
                                       Benefits
['Health Care & Insurance (2747)', 'Life Insurance (2423)', 'Disability Insurance (674)', 'Dental..]
```

Ideally it should be like this.

```
Health Care & Insurance  Life Insurance    Disability Insurance..
      2747                  2423                 674
```

I have tried but cannot think of a way to do this because characters are returned one at a time, so cannot find a way to make the headline text `key` and the value of it as `value` and I cannot come up with a way to create a `dict` out of this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the string find method to find the brackets and extract the value to save it into a dictionary

```
Benefits=['Health Care & Insurance (2747)', 'Life Insurance (2423)', 'Disability Insurance (674)']
info_dict={}
for benift in Benefits:
    key= benift[:benift.find("(")]
    value = benift[benift.find("(")+1:benift.find(")")]
    info_dict[key]=int(value)

print(info_dict)
```

Output is :

```
{'Health Care & Insurance ': 2747, 'Life Insurance ': 2423, 'Disability Insurance ': 674}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the list in this way:

```
lst = ['Health Care & Insurance', 2747, 'Life Insurance',2423, 'Disability Insurance',674]

def Convert(a):
    it = iter(a)
    res_dct = dict(zip(it, it))
    return res_dct

print(Convert(lst))
```

output:

```
 {'Health Care & Insurance': 2747, 'Life Insurance': 2423, 'Disability Insurance': 674}
```